# How to apply Vue.js scoped styles to components loaded via view-router?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

How can I apply Vue.js scoped styles to components loaded via `<view-router>`.

Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <div id="admin">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
#admin {
  .actions {
    display: none;
    span {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

When I visit the `/posts` a component named `Posts` will be loaded, inside this component I have a

```
<div class="actions">
  some content
</div>
```

The problem is that the style defined in `#admin` is not applied to `.action` element. When not scoped, this works fine. The problem come when the `#admin` component styling is `scoped`.

Is there any way to do that while keeping the `.actions` style inside the `admin` component scoped style tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is probably what you want https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors

Since your code snippet specifically uses SCSS you'll have to use the /deep/ combinator.

---

If you want a selector in scoped styles to be "deep", i.e. affecting child components, you can use the >>> combinator:

```
<style scoped>
.a >>> .b { /* ... */ }
</style>
```

The above will be compiled into:

```
.a[data-v-f3f3eg9] .b { /* ... */ }
```

> Some pre-processors, such as SASS, may not be able to parse >>> properly. In those cases you can use the /deep/ combinator instead - it's an alias for >>> and works exactly the same.

---

So you'd end up with:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  #admin {
    some-property: some-style;

    /deep/ .actions {
      some-property: some-style;
    }
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Webpack is just spitting out the `>>>` as-is for me. Is there something special I have to do in `webpack.config.js`?

Comment: @333 what preprocessor are you using? (if any at all)

Comment: At the risk of sounding like a child, I don't know ... my `vue-loader` options look like this: `{ loaders: { scss: "vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader" } }`

Comment: @333 No worries! So it looks like you're using Sass (and probably SCSS specifically) so in your Vue file if you have `<style lang="scss">` you'd have to use the `/deep/` combinator as seen in my second code example, instead of the `>>>` example.

Comment: It's still spitting it out verbatim for me.

Comment: I actually asked my own question on this, but I'm commenting here because you seem to know how it works. My question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48032006/how-do-i-use-deep-or-in-vue-js

Answer (score 3):

You can put styles in a separate file and reference it from all components that need it:

```html
<style src="path/to/your/styles" lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

Comment: Thank you!  That was an excellent answer.  Not sure why anyone else doesn't like it!

Comment: This is not a good solution, it creates multiple `style` tags on `head`, and you can't add any rules to this style.

Comment: You have probably multiple `style` tags in development mode. In production, it depends on how you configure the chunks with Webpack.

Comment: tks, That's great

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `router-view` tag wont pass styles to its child is because the `router-view` itself is not a style-able html tag, therefore you cant apply any styles to it. You can try but it wont render.

**Reason:** The `router-view` is essentially a template tag, or placeholder for Vue to anchor to and insert the `component` or `View` that gets called for that route. As a result, the `router-view` tag wont appear in the compiled markup, you will only see the `View` or `Component` thats being loaded.

It sort of works the same way as the App Entry point works for the Vue App into the index.html file. At least that's my experience and knowledge.

Also, @Antonio Trapani good answer, I would add that you can even go as far as having a scss file with all your global styles, or styles needed across multiple components, then just @import the styles into the `App.vue` that will give you access across the whole app. Also, IME.

Hope this helps some.
Cheers.