# How do I use /deep/ or >>> or ::v-deep in Vue.js?

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack, sass, vue-cli

So, I've read [here](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/scoped-css.html) that in Vue.js, you can use `/deep/` or `>>>` in a selector in order to create style rules that apply to elements inside of child components. However, attempting to use this in my styles, whether in SCSS or in plain old CSS, doesn't work. Instead, they are sent to the browser verbatim, and therefore have no effect. For example:

**home.vue:**

```
<style lang="css" scoped>
.autocomplete >>> .autocomplete-input 
{
// ...
}
</style>
```

**generated css:**

```
<style type="text/css">
.autocomplete >>> .autocomplete-input[data-v-2bda0c9a]
{
//...
}
</style>
```

**what I want:**

```
<style type="text/css">
.autocomplete[data-v-2bda0c9a] .autocomplete-input
{
//...
}
</style>
```

My webpack configuration pertaining to `vue-loader` looks like this:

```
// ...
{
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: "vue-loader",
    options: {
        loaders: {
            scss: "vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader"
        }
    }
}
// ...
```

So my question is, how do I get this `>>>` operator to work?

I've already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46964259/3508956) answer, but I'm doing exactly that and it doesn't work...

Comment: @connexo The Vue Loader itself supports a [scoped](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/scoped-css.html) modifier for CSS that is not related to the defunct native-to-CSS `scoped` modifier.

Comment: @connexo @RoyJ removing the `scoped` attribute and the `>>>` operator does indeed make the style rule work, but it's less than optimal. As Roy J pointed out, this `scoped` attribute has nothing to do with the W3C.

Comment: Did you get this working? With `<style scoped>`, `>>>` should work (`.autocomplete >>> .autocomplete-input`) and with `<style lang="scss" scoped>`, `/deep/` should work (`.autocomplete /deep/ .autocomplete-input`) (tested with nuxt 1.4 / vue 2.5)

Comment: [deep-selectors](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors) this should useful

Answer (score 441, accepted):

#### Vue 2.0 - 2.6

<sup>*The following also works in Vue 3 but is deprecated.*</sup>

**Sass:**   Use `::v-deep`

```css
::v-deep .child-class {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

***Not* using Sass:**   Use `>>>`

```css
>>> .child-class {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

With either syntax, the `<style>` tag for this component must be `scoped`:

```html
<style scoped>
```

---

#### Vue 3 (and Vue 2.7)

In Vue 3, the `::v-` prefix is now [deprecated](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-style.html#deep-selectors) and we no longer need `>>>`.  We can use the unified `:deep` selector *whether using Sass or not*, but now it's recommended to use parentheses with the selector.

**Use `:deep(.child-class)`**

```css
:deep(.child-class) {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

<sup>This also works in Vue 2.7 (final Vue 2 release)</sup>

---

#### Vue 3 new selectors

Additionally, in Vue 3, there is a [new feature](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-style.html#slotted-selectors) for components with a `<slot>` that enables styling passed slot content.

**Slot content**   Use `:slotted(.child-class)`

```css
:slotted(.slot-class) {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

And lastly, in Vue 3, there is a [new feature](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-style.html#global-selectors) to register global styles even from a `scoped` component:

**Global styles**   Use `:global(.my-class)`

```css
:global(.my-class) {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

With any syntax, the `<style>` tag for this component must be `scoped`:

```html
<style scoped>
```

---

#### Summary

In Vue 2:

- The `/deep/` syntax is deprecated
- Use `::v-deep` with Sass, use `>>>` without Sass

In Vue 3:

- `::v-deep .child-class` is deprecated in favor of `:deep(.child-class)`
- The `::v-` prefix is deprecated in favor of `:`
- The `>>>` syntax is deprecated
- The `/deep/` syntax is deprecated
- There are new `:slotted` and `:global` selectors

With every version/syntax, the `<style>` tag for this component must be `scoped`:

```html
<style scoped>
```

Comment: Confirming `:deep()` syntax works in Vue 2.7

Answer (score 31):

**Avoid using `/deep/` and instead use `::v-deep`**

Any scoped `component's` css can be changed by using `deep selector`
but sooner `/deep/` will get deprecated

Vue Github reference - https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/913

**Use** `::v-deep` in this case,and avoid deprecated `/deep/`

Reference - [Deep Selector](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors)

Just inspect class of the rendered `element` which you want to modify using `devtools` in chrome or any browser console.

Then, In you consuming `component`, modify it

```
<style scoped>
::v-deep .custom-component-class {
   background: red; //
}
</style>
```

Comment: I have also just discovered that `/deep/` breaks the build using Babel 7, so in Sass `::v-deep` becomes the only option

Answer (score 26):

I've successfully used /deep/ in Vue's scoped SCSS stylesheets with this structure:

```
.parent-class {
  & /deep/ .child-class {
    background-color: #000;
  }
}
```

Edit: /deep/ is being deprecated, if it no longer works for you please refer to the other answer that explains ::v-deep

Comment: Please check the other answers "/deep/" is being deprecated!

Answer (score 8):

::v-deep usage as a combinator has been deprecated. Use :deep() instead.

```
:deep(.child-class) {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: How to use it with multiple classes ?

Comment: You put :deep() around every comma-separated selector. What used to be ".button1, .button2", now becomes ":deep(.button1), :deep(.button2)".

Comment: Multiple `:deep` for 2+ selectors suck. I have wysiwyg editor and want to style p, h1, h2, h3, etc.

Answer (score 3):

For me, the only thing that worked was

```
<style scoped>.  // sass and scss didn't work
  >>> .deep-selector {
    ...
  }
</style>
```

Comment: I agree: this is a nice and short answer that works in all use-cases. It's also the only one currently mentioned in the vue-loader docs.

Answer (score 3):

Though it is not found in the [Documentation](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors), the answer is that the component you are attempting to reach cannot be the root component. Wrap your single component in a `<div>` and it should work using `::v-deep` on scoped `scss` as others have explained.

Comment: I had this issue. :deep did not work for me until wrapping the whole thing in a <div>. The root component in this case was the one that also had the first div class on it in the component. For others, to verify this, try targeting the :deep on a second level down component. If that works either do that, or add a div in the parent where you set the :deep css.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding

```js
options: { styleIsolation: 'shared' }, // add this
methods: {
  yourFunc1 () {
  }
}
```

```css
.pet-info{
  ::v-deep .title {
    width: 51px !important;
    background-color: red !important
  }
}
```

Config this in the components like the methods, it's the same level like methods.

Comment: It's work for the uniapp / mpvue (WeChat mini-program) project. This config doesn't exist in vueJs

Answer (score 0):

To override the CSS properties of a specific element in Vue.js use
Vuetify, below workded for me:

```
<style scoped>
::v-deep .v-overlay__content {
    contain: none !important;
}
</style>
```

OR

```
<style scoped>
>>> .v-overlay__content {
    contain: none !important;
}
</style>
```