# VueJS: Modify SVG fill style with reactive variables

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, svg

I have a SVG that looks like:

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 120 121">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1{fill:#fff}.background{fill:#f00}.trim{fill:#0f0}.foreground{fill:#00f}
    </style>
    <mask id="mask" x="4" y="4" width="111" height="113" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <g id="mask-2">
        <path id="path-1" class="cls-1" d="M5 50a58 58 0 0 0 19 11l4-8q5 25-1 57c1 0 18 7 32 7s32-7 32-7q-5-31 0-57l4 8q13-5 19-11c-9-16-12-30-17-35q-6-4-24-11H47q-19 7-24 11c-5 5-7 17-18 35z"/>
      </g>
    </mask>
    <mask id="mask-2-2" x="5" y="4" width="110" height="113" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <g id="mask-2-3" data-name="mask-2">
        <path id="path-1-2" data-name="path-1" class="cls-1" d="M5 50a58 58 0 0 0 19 11l4-8q5 25-1 57c1 0 18 7 32 7s32-7 32-7q-5-31 0-57l4 8q13-5 19-11c-9-16-12-30-17-35q-6-4-24-11H47q-19 7-24 11c-5 5-7 17-18 35z"/>
      </g>
    </mask>
    <mask id="mask-3" x="3" y="4" width="111" height="113" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <g id="mask-2-4" data-name="mask-2">
        <path id="path-1-3" data-name="path-1" class="cls-1" d="M5 50a58 58 0 0 0 19 11l4-8q5 25-1 57c1 0 18 7 32 7s32-7 32-7q-5-31 0-57l4 8q13-5 19-11c-9-16-12-30-17-35q-6-4-24-11H47q-19 7-24 11c-5 5-7 17-18 35z"/>
      </g>
    </mask>
    <mask id="mask-4" x="5" y="4" width="113" height="113" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <g id="mask-2-5" data-name="mask-2">
        <path id="path-1-4" data-name="path-1" class="cls-1" d="M5 50a58 58 0 0 0 19 11l4-8q5 25-1 57c1 0 18 7 32 7s32-7 32-7q-5-31 0-57l4 8q13-5 19-11c-9-16-12-30-17-35q-6-4-24-11H47q-19 7-24 11c-5 5-7 17-18 35z"/>
      </g>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <g id="Page-1">
    <path class="background" d="M5 50a58 58 0 0 0 19 11l4-8q5 25-1 57c1 0 18 7 32 7s32-7 32-7q-5-31 0-57l4 8q13-5 19-11c-9-16-12-30-17-35q-6-4-24-11H47q-19 7-24 11c-5 5-7 17-18 35z" id="Path-3"/>
    <g mask="url(#mask)">
      <path id="Path-7" class="trim" d="M28 54l-5-44L4 50l22 17 2-13z"/>
    </g>
    <g mask="url(#mask-2-2)">
      <path id="Path-7-Copy" class="trim" d="M91 54l5-44 19 39-23 18-1-13z"/>
    </g>
    <g mask="url(#mask-3)">
      <path id="Path-6" class="foreground" d="M6 46a68 68 0 0 0 21 12q2 2-1 3l-15-4-8-10z"/>
    </g>
    <g mask="url(#mask-4)">
      <path id="Path-6-Copy" class="foreground" d="M114 46a65 65 0 0 1-20 12q-2 1 1 3l22-11v-3z"/>
    </g>
    <path id="Path-4" class="foreground" d="M47 3h26l2 2a99 99 0 0 1-16 1 77 77 0 0 1-14-1z"/>
    <g id="Shirt-Collar">
      <path class="foreground" d="M60 3h13l2 1s1 4-7 7a36 36 0 0 1-8 2 36 36 0 0 1-8-2c-8-3-7-7-7-7l2-1z"/>
      <path id="Combined-Shape" class="background" d="M59 10c-11 0-10-6-10-6h23s1 6-11 6h-2z"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

There are three classes in here `background` `trim` and `foreground` that I would like to edit reactively in a VueJS component.

I also have 50 of these SVG's that I would like to switch in and out as well, preferably using some sort of reactive `shirtId` property.

But I can't figure out how to do that.

I can't embed it like this:

```
<img src="1.svg" />
```

Because then I can't edit the three classes.

It seems like I need to embed it directly into the component so I got as far as this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-d2yi7

Where i'm defining the colours in the `<style>` section at the end:

```
<style>
    .cls-1{fill:#fff}
    .background{fill:#f00}
    .foreground{fill:#00f}
    .trim{fill:#0f0}
</style>
```

But this isn't reactive.

So then I tried this:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-ddj72

Now the background colour can be set reactively using the `backgroundStyle` property.

But this method would mean creating 50 different components containing each SVG edited with this inline style tag.

I had a look at this SVG Loader: https://github.com/visualfanatic/vue-svg-loader
But I couldn't see how it would help in my case with the changing of the css properties.

Preferably what I would like to be able to do would be something like:

```
<my-custom-svg foreground="green" background="red" trim="blue" id="17"></my-custom-svg>
```

And then a `MyCustomSvg` that loads 17.svg and changes the fill on the three classes.

But I don't know if that's possible or how to get from where I am now to that point.

Comment: You could define your <svg> as a Vue component, then you would have all the benefits from Vue but you'd have to transform it. You could then also use your desired syntax.

Comment: You could also use the loader you mentioned. This will import the <svg> fully into the DOM. In the parent component, you would define the styles. Be aware that if you use scoped styles, you'll probably need the [`/deep/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52378590/3233827) selector to target those elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like [`CSS custom properties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) could help.

```css
<style>
    .background { fill: var(--background); }
    .foreground { fill: var(--foreground); }
    .trim { fill: var(--trim); }
</style>
```

Then you can change custom property depending on props.

```
<template>
  <div :style="cssProps">
    <--! Your SVG here -->
  /div>
</template>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  pops: ['background', 'foreground', 'trim'],
  computed: {
    cssProps() {
      return {
        '--background': this.background,
        '--foreground': this.foreground,
        '--trim': this.trim
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Check out this [pen](https://codepen.io/richardtallent/pen/yvpERW/).

Comment: Interesting I have never seen something like this, the `--` just having a play now