# Is it possible to use deep/child css selectors with parcel like possible with vue-loader?

Tags: vuejs2, parceljs

I'm trying to get a child/deep selector going within SCSS. However the output css is not as expected. This issue is similar to [How do I use /deep/ or >>> in Vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48032006/how-do-i-use-deep-or-in-vue-js)
However they use webpack and vue-loader rather then parcel.

I've tried:

```
.example >>> .example-child {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

This however generates

```css
.example > .example-child[data-v-bb9328] {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

While I would need the following:

```css
.example[data-v-bb9328] > .example-child {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

The Parcel documentation is quite barebone and I couldn't really find any notes in regards to this in the github. Is this not a supported feature or am I just not seeing something?

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="example">
      <div class="example-child">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'TestExample',
  }
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .example::v-deep {
    .example-child {
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
  }
</style>
```

It produces:

```html
<style type="text/css">
.example[data-v-b07474d4] .example-child{
  border:1px solid red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Didn't do the trick, it ended up being parsed to ```.example::v-deep .example-child[data-v-bb9328] {```

Comment: It's weird. In my case it works like a charm. Take a look on updated answer.

Comment: Tried your full block, still the same result. What are you using as setup? Are you using parcel as well? If so I can see if I can get this to reproduce in a small dummy project.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that we talking about parcel. I'm using Webpack 4.