# How to override max-width of tool-tip in bootstrap-vue

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am using [Bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/tooltip) to show tool-tip. Works good but I can't increase width of tool-tip beyond a limit.

I found some related issues and discussions on [github](https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/2051) but couldn't resolve the issue.

I am not using sass or anything. I am simply importing `TooltipPlugin` from `bootstrap-vue`.

Also tried solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58819835/9640177) setting

```
.tooltip .tooltip-inner{
  max-width: 500px !important;
  width: 400px !important;
}
```

does nothing. also tried setting `--max-width: none;` -- but no luck

How do I increase the width of tool-tip to make the content readable.

Comment: Did you try the solution from here? https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/4950

Comment: Yes I went through the solution but can't understand how to implement that in my case.

Comment: Also tried setting css variable following this question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/41370741/9640177

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increase the width of the tooltip in Bootstrap-Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58819835/how-to-increase-the-width-of-the-tooltip-in-bootstrap-vue)

Comment: The CSS logic is working fine for me. Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) to show the issue happening.