# How do I change the hover background and the background on click on a Bootstrap Vue dropdown item?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

The default background color on hover is a light-ish gray. I have the following dropdown in a navbar.

```
<b-nav-item-dropdown text="TOOLS" right>
    <b-dropdown-item href="#" class="dropdown-mine">1</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item href="#" class="dropdown-mine">2</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item href="#" class="dropdown-mine">3</b-dropdown-item>
    <b-dropdown-item href="#" class="dropdown-mine">4</b-dropdown-item>
</b-nav-item-dropdown>
```

I tried to change the hover background it with the following CSS

```
.dropdown-item:hover{
    background-color:red;
 }
```

Edit: Changing dropdown-item for dropdown-mine worked. However

When I try to change the background on click it doesn't work:

```
.dropdown-mine:focus{
    background-color:green;
 }
```

I tried adding !important to it but no result.

Edit: I also tried .nav-item-dropdown

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, you are trying to apply your CSS styles to a class called `dropdown-item`. Your class should be `dropdown-mine` or if you want to apply it to all the dropdown-items, it will simply be the name of the tag without the dot.

Comment: @pensum appears to be correct, change it to `.dropdown-mine:hover{
    background-color:red;
 }`

Comment: The `b-dropdown-item` component adds the `dropdown-item` class. `dropdown-mine` simply extends the class list.

Comment: I forgot about something in my question. I edited it

Comment: Have you inspected the styles in DevTools to see if your rules are being applied and that they are possibly being overridden by bootstrap styles? That would narrow things down a little.

Comment: Yes. My style isn't being applied on the dropdown-item:focus class, However adding !important to my code isn't doing anything

Comment: nvm, i had to add !important to .dropdown-item, not .dropdown-mine, it works now, thank you

Comment: I will post an answer that could lighten your code if it helps, tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Perhaps you should try this:**

```
.dropdown-item {
  & ::v-deep .dropdown-mine {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

I am not familiar with Vue.js but I have found a similar question on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48032006/how-do-i-use-deep-or-in-vue-js) that gave this answer. You can read more about the `::v-deep` selector [here](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors).