# Vue Styling a Child Component Form and Form Elements

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, components

I am trying to style a form within a child component and am having problems with the `\deep\`, `>>>`, and `::v-deep` selector targeting of `<form>`, `<input>`, or `<button>` elements.

**// Parent Component**

```
<template>
    <div class="form-bottom">
        <login-form :is-modal="false"></login-form>
    </div>
<template>

<style scoped>
    .form-bottom /deep/ form {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 0em;
    }
</style>
```

**// Parent Component**

```
<template>
    <form autocomplete="off" @submit.prevent="login" method="post" role="form" action="" class="login-form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="email">E-mail</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" ref="email" class="form-username form-control" placeholder="user@example.com" v-model="email" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" class="form-password form-control" placeholder="Password..." v-model="password" required />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" ref="password" class="btn">Sign in</button> <a href="/password/forgot" class="forgot-password" @click.prevent="forgotPasswordModal">Forgot Password</a><!--<a href="/password/forgot">Forgot Password</a>-->
    </form>
</template>
```

The output CSS and HTML in browser console.

**// Parent CSS**

```
.form-bottom /deep/ form[_v-41cced72] {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0em;
}
```

**// Child Template**

```
<form autocomplete="off" method="post" role="form" action="" _v-3353696a="" class="login-form">
    <div _v-3353696a="" class="form-group">
        <label for="email" _v-3353696a="" class="sr-only">E-mail</label> 
        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="user@example.com" required="required" _v-3353696a="" class="form-username form-control">
    </div>
    <div _v-3353696a="" class="form-group">
        <label for="password" _v-3353696a="" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password..." required="required" _v-3353696a="" class="form-password form-control">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" _v-3353696a="" class="btn">Sign in</button> <a href="/password/forgot" _v-3353696a="" class="forgot-password">Forgot Password</a>
</form>
```

The resulting Child HTML has an attribute of `_v-3353696a=""` on the form element. While the Parent CSS has a selector of `.form-bottom /deep/ form[_v-41cced72]`. Should the `/deep/` selector be compiled into a scoped attribute?

Comment: Remove "scoped" from <style scoped>

Comment: The Vue documentation says to use this within scoped https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#child-component-root-elements

Comment: Ok. What element has the class "form-bottom"? I didn't see any tag with this class in the code you provided.

Comment: its in the parent, i just updated my question to include it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48032006/how-do-i-use-deep-or-in-vue-js/55368933#55368933

Comment: @Dan i just saw this post and another like it and tried changing my language to SASS and SCSS neither are converting the /deep/ selector into an attribute

Comment: Check it again `/deep/` is deprecated.  Use `<style lang="scss" scoped>`

Comment: @Dan After switching lang="scss" and trying both ::v-deep and >>> I am still not seeing either being converted to an attribute. Should I? I am seeing the SCSS being converted into CSS but still see ::v-deep at the beginning of the selector in style sheet loaded in my browser and >>> is converted to a single >.

Comment: Did you choose sass when you created your project in vue cli?  If not, I recommend creating a new project and choosing `dart-sass`.