# :first-child styles not beeing applied in Vue Component

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, scope

**Problem:**

Normally the first `<User>` should have `margin-left: 0px` and should align to the left with the other elements but this doesn't work as you can see in the screenshot below. Anyone got an idea how to fix this properly?

[image]

`sidebar.scss` Code:

```
.user {
  margin-left: -8px;

  &:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

`Sidebar.vue` Code

```
<template>
  <section class="sidebar">
    <slot></slot>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "Sidebar"
  }
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
  @import 'sidebar';
</style>
```

`Profile.vue` Code

```
<template>
  <main>
    <Sidebar>
      <Header text="Members" :button="{text: 'Edit'}" hasBorder="true"></Header>
      <User img="..."></User>
      <User img="..."></User>
      <User img="..."></User>
      <User img="..."></User>
      <Button color="grey" isRounded="true" isIconOnly="true"></Button>
    </Sidebar>
  </main>
</template>
```

`User.vue` code:

```
<template>
  <div class="user">
    <img v-if="this.img" :src="this.img" :alt="this.name">
    <div v-if="!this.img"></div>
    <h6 v-if="this.name">{{this.name}}</h6>
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: @YomS. nope unfortunately not. I can't see the style in the compiled code anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too sure if this is at all the problem here, but note that `:first-child` does not pick the first occurrence by the mere class name, but by the tag within a parent element. In other words: you cannot use a class name to apply `:first-child` to. Instead, use something more semantic like

```
<ul class="users">
  <li class="user"></li> <!-- there is your component -->
  <li class="user"></li>
  <li class="user"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yeah I think this was the problem. I thought too complicated haha. I changed `:first-child` to `:first-of-type` and it worked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `::v-deep` to change `scoped` css.

I answered this already but I have an old and more descriptive answer available which might be a help to you to understand the usage https://stackoverflow.com/a/56698470/7358308

https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors

**Note: Don not use `/deep/` because it's deprecated and also `>>>` combinator will not work too as you are using `sass` preprocessor**

```
::v-deep {
  .user {
    margin-left: -8px;

    &:first-child {
     margin-left: 0;
   }
  }

}
```

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately. The `margin-left:-8px` are working tough, so the scope shouldn't be affected in my opinion. It's just weird that everything is working except the pseudo-element

Comment: Have you tried applying any other style like `background` or any major differentiating `style`, it seems like there requires minimally reproducible example

Comment: Yep same issue. `background: red` keeps compiling to all `.user` elements. If I try to add `background: blue` to `:first-child` it's not working again.

Answer (score 0):

Scoped style is not shared between parent and child components. You have several options:

1. Make style global by removing scoped attribute from style section in parent.
2. Import style into the target component (User).
3. Use the deep combinator in scoped style.

   `>>>`.user {
     ...
   }

or

```
/deep/ .user {
  ...
}
```

or

```
::v-deep .user {
  ...
}
```

Comment: isn't working unfortunately. It's weird tough that the styles are applied to `.user`. Only the styles for the pseudo-element are ignored