# How to remove underline from v-text filed or v-input filed

Tags: vuetify.js

I try to remove underline from  v-input, v-text or v-autocomplete fileds in Vuetify, but I couldn't find how

Is there any way to remove underline from v-input, v-text or v-autocomplete fileds in Vuetify.

Answer (score 34):

On v-text add "solo" and "flat" prop. works on v-input and v-autocomplete.

```
<v-text-field flat solo></v-text-field>
```

Flat: description from vuetify documentation
"Removes elevation (shadow) added to element when using the solo or solo-inverted props"

There is a playground in vuetify which can help you as well.
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/

Comment: this works well, but you may have a lot of extra spacing, esp if it is inside a v-data-table.  adding these other props will help: `flat solo class="ma-0 pa-0" hide-details`

Comment: This remove label, any solution for it??

Answer (score 7):

Use the deep selector as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48032006/how-do-i-use-deep-or-in-vue-js). You have to override the v-input__slot::before class like that:

```
>>> .v-input__slot::before {
  border-style: none !important;
}
```

It removes the underlines from the elements you specified in the question.
If you do not want to remove all the underlines in a component simultaneously, but only on some specified, do it like that:

```
.some-style >>> .v-input__slot::before {
  border-style: none !important;
}
```

And remove the underlines only on the elements of your choice:

```
<v-text-field class="some-style"></v-text-field>
```

Answer (score 2):

Spend sometime on this one you need to override the before css style

```
.v-text-field > .v-input__control > .v-input__slot:before {
  border-style: none; 
}
```