# "Transparent" v-text-field in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I need to create `v-text-field` without background, borders or shadows, is that possible? Docs specify only these types:

[image]

But neither of them suit my needs.

What's the simplest way to achieve this?

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62775729/how-to-remove-underline-from-v-text-filed-or-v-input-filed) but it didn't remove the background (in dark mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override default `v-text-field` styles in your css.

```html
<v-text-field
    class="text-field-transparent"
    solo
    flat
/>
```

```css
.text-field-transparent  .v-input__slot {
  background: transparent !important;
}
```