# Remove underline from underlined Vuetify text-field

Tags: html, css, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

Given the Vuetify [v-text-field](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/) component

( [Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqlUctuwjAQ/JXIZ2wXcSqiFb33DzAHEy/CrV+yN2kR4t+7DqGiUKmVOCU7O7szs14d2EtKou+AzdkCwSenEZ5VaJpFz3VKw+9QeG3DWA01wifyrQVnGqc34J4Ue61fxZrWgc5646DpdbY6IPW6YCA7G8AQwUAoFvcEt9En3SJhO2uAG0BtXaGG7jDWVdHFTGXK1uu8J0SeLckLT7U4uV3I7xRswqxPMSPxkngrMVDIQ6WrsVEUmzcDUjG6Qq0V2yGmMpeyNYHGDDjbZxEAZUheLokmcxfQevIb/XImZuKBa5d2WjxKYwtetgUUzzc5fhTItEyxyYUc2i1F+lNyZJLSVExnJ4kR43T7UjVudksS7CHzDPXykP8b7Wrst3hXlJuI1cVRhSM9AL34e7m6fVuGu6/OZu/LPmyrq9ZV8ThhPwyThdMkW38Bs+r7FQ==) )

```
<v-text-field label="Label" clearable variant="underlined" density="compact" hide-details="auto" color="primary" />
```

I want to remove the underline from it so I have a blank input without borders. I tried custom CSS like

- `text-decoration: none`
- `border-bottom: none`
- `border-bottom-color: transparent`

but that didn't work. Do you have any ideas?

---

Sidenote:

This input fills a slot inside a table cell and it's a requirement to get rid of the underline because there already is a cell border.

Comment: I think this has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62775729/how-to-remove-underline-from-v-text-filed-or-v-input-filed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [plain variant](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields/#variant):

```html
<v-text-field label="Label" clearable variant="plain" density="compact" hide-details="auto" color="primary"/>
```

Comment: oh damn, stupid me ... example at the beginning didn't show that