# Vue style scoped

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

```
<template>
<div>
    <test />
    <test1 />
    <test2 />
</div>
</template>

<style scoped>
@import '@/main.css'


</style>
```

I know scoped will not let parent's style leak to child components.

But if I want the `import style` leak to all child components, and not let it leak to global.

This style is used for all child components, but not for global styles.

The way I found is import style in every child components, but if there are too much child components, I need too import style in every child components.

Any way to do that?

Comment: use `/deep/` infront of your childs like `/deep/ .child {  ..  }`

Answer (score 1):

This is my [codesanbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-http-k9r2u?file=/src/App.vue).

If you want a selector in `scoped` styles to be "deep", i.e. affecting child components, you can use the `>>>` combinator:

Parent component:

```js
<template>
  <div class="parent">
    <test1/>
    <test2/>
  </div>
</template>
<style scoped>
.parent >>> .child {
 // ...
}
</style>
```

Child component:

```js
<template>
<div class="child"></div>
</template>
```

The above will be compiled into:

```html
<div class="parent" data-v-f3f3eg9>
 <div class="child"></div>
 <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.parent[data-v-f3f3eg9] .child {}
```

More tips on how to use `deep` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48032006/how-do-i-use-deep-or-in-vue-js)

Comment: I need import style to affect child components, but not affect global

Comment: @deepL Wait a minute, I will create a codesanbox for you

Comment: This is for custom style. But if  `import style` is library, like bootstrap, is it still some way to do that? 
I want to use bootstrap but I only want its class affect some component.