# Remove Box Shadow from Expandable Data Table in Vuetify

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I can't seem to remove the box shadow in the expandable data table in Vuetify. I tried using inline css by adding `box-shadow: none` and even

```css
<style scope>
.v-data-table__expanded .v-data-table__expanded__content {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

I also tried using `elevation="0"` in the data table hoping it would work but to no avail it still doesn't. Can anyone help me?

This is what it currently looks like:
[image]

I just used the code in vuetify but for convenience this is the code:

```
    <div class="my-6">
      <v-text-field
        v-model="search"
        label="Search"
        class="mx-4"
        prepend-inner-icon="mdi-magnify"
        outlined
        dense
        hide-details
      ></v-text-field>
    </div>
    <template>
      <v-data-table
        :headers="dessertHeaders"
        :items="desserts"
        :single-expand="true"
        :expanded.sync="expanded"
        item-key="name"
        dense
        show-expand
        :search="search"
        :custom-filter="filter"
        elevation="0"
      >
        <template v-slot:expanded-item="{ headers, item }" elevation="0">
          <td :colspan="headers.length" elevation="0">More info about {{ item.name }}</td>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
    </template>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following CSS:

```css
.v-data-table__expanded.v-data-table__expanded__content {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Since the classes are on the same element, you don't want a space in between them, which signifies a parent / (grand)child relationship.

Here's another option that wouldn't require the `!important` modifier:

```css
.v-data-table > .v-data-table__wrapper tbody tr.v-data-table__expanded__content {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: I tried both versions and for some reason it still didn't work :( Thank you though, that was informative

Comment: Here you go, the proof: https://codepen.io/sh0ber/pen/gOwBZdN This is using the Vuetify example from the docs with just that style applied.

Comment: Also, your `<style>` tag has a wrong attribute `scope`.  It should be `scoped`.  Try to remove it as well.

Comment: It's working now! And yes the scoped was a typo. Thank you so much. The ``scoped`` was the problem all along. Thank you, you're a life saver!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it helped :)  You could also try the `>>>` syntax as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48032006/how-do-i-use-deep-or-in-vue-js/55368933#55368933) if you need to keep the `scoped` attribute.

Comment: Ohh this is the first time I heard of that. Will do! Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if anyone having trouble with the above solution By Dan. This worked for me as mentioned by him in the comment section. See his comment or go to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48032006/how-do-i-use-deep-or-in-vue-js/55368933#55368933) for more.

```
.v-data-table >>> .v-data-table__wrapper tbody tr.v-data-table__expanded__content {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: This work for me! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As of today use `$data-table-expanded-content-box-shadow` variable to remove box shadow like this
`$data-table-expanded-content-box-shadow: none;`