# v::deep how to reach certain element

Tags: css, vue.js, sass

Can anyone tell me is it possible with vuejs, `v::deep` to select class `media-library-dropzone` and `media-library-help` and how. I have to change css only in this component

My example is here: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9zuS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `::v-deep .media-library-dropzone` if you're using Sass (as in your case apparently) or `>>> .media-library-dropzone` if not.

As explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55368933/8816585