# How to pass css styles to plugins in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

I use Vue-Editor.

```html
<vue-editor id="editor" ref="editor" v-model="content" :use-custom-image-handler="true" @image-added ="added" @image-removed ="deleted" :key="componentKey"/>
```

On mobile devices, the icons are to small. I like to increase the icons size on mobile devices, but on medium devices, I like to keep the default size.

If I do it in this way, the size changes for all pages not only for the current page:

```html
<style>
.p {
    color: black
}

.ql-snow.ql-toolbar button {
    height: 35px !important;
    width: 35px !important;
}

.quillWrapper .ql-snow.ql-toolbar button svg {
    width: 35px !important;
    height: 35px !important;
}
</style>
```

If I do it with `<style scoped>` it doesn't pass the css to the plugin component.

How I can change the css for the plugin only in one Vue component without having a global effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep `scoped` but then, you need to make a [deep selector](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors) like `>>> .ql-snow.ql-toolbar button` to select the 3rd party library.

If using SASS, use `::v-deep`, more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55368933/8816585).