# AWS Cognito - How to customise the input fields?

Tags: javascript, css, amazon-web-services, vue.js, amazon-cognito

### THE SITUATION:

In my Vue app, I am using the [aws authenticator](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/auth/authenticator/q/framework/vue) to handle login/signup. 
I need to customize the style, but it's a bit tricky since its structure is made of shadow DOM.

[image: aws authenticator]

### MODIFYING VARIABLES:

So far I only managed to modify some amplify variables.

[image]

This is how I did it:

```css
:root {
  --amplify-background-color: transparent;
  --amplify-secondary-color: white;
  --amplify-primary-contrast: white;
  --amplify-primary-color: #E00C1D;
}
```

Side note. Targeteting `amplify-sign-in` instead of `:root` would also work, but logically that style would apply only for the login form and not for the signup (`amplify-sign-up`) form. 
Custom style targeting `:root` applies to both login and signup form.

### CUSTOMIZE THE INPUT FIELD:

Here is where I got stuck.
The color of the text inside the input is given by the  `--amplify-secondary-color` var, which in my case needs to be white. But in this way the text of the input is not visible on a white background.

This is the HTML structure of the `amplify-sign-in`. The `input` is inside `amplify-input`.
[image: amplify-input]

This is the style for the `.input` class. As you can see the color is controlled by the `--color` var 
[image]

This is what the `--color` var refers to:
[image]

### MY ATTEMPTS:

I have tried several approaches but none worked.
I tried to target the `.input` class, the `input`, the `amplify-input`, or to change the `--color` var.

These are some attempts:

```css
:host {
  --color: red !important;
}

:host(.input) {
  color: red !important;
  --color: red !important;
}

amplify-input {
  --color: red !important;

  & .input {
    color:red !important;
    --color: red !important;
  }
}
```

#### THE DOCS:

This are the [docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/ui/customization/customizing-css/q/framework/vue) concerning the css customization. Unfortunately the documentation is quite poor

#### TESTING:

The quickest way to set a working example, using Vue, would be to setup this sample from the amplify-js-samples package: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js-samples/tree/main/samples/vue/auth/authenticator

#### THE QUESTION:

How can I modify the input text of the aws authenticator?

Comment: Do you mean you want it like this? https://nimb.ws/E0CZQl

Comment: Well yes, I need to be able to change the input text color, without affecting the --amplify-secondary-color var.

Comment: Do not post screenshots of your code but the actual code in text.

Comment: I posted my code in text. Those are screenshots taken from the Elements tab of the Chrome Developer tools. They are the style of the input used in the default AWS cognito.

Answer (score 1):

It might make sense to update to the latest version of Amplify UI for Vue.

There is updated documentation for styling
https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/vue/connected-components/authenticator/customization#css-style

It also links to another page showing all the CSS variables
https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/vue/theming/css-variables

The updated version has more granular CSS classes, such as:

- `--amplify-colors-font-primary`
- `--amplify-colors-font-interactive`
- `--amplify-colors-font-active`
- `--amplify-colors-font-focus`

Answer (score 0):

Try following scss,

```
amplify-sign-in /deep/ {
    amplify-input {
        > input.input {
            color : red !important;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have tried it but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using SCSS, you may do it like this

```css
::v-deep amplify-input input[type='email'] { // can of course be more specific here
  color: red !important;
}
```

The `!important` is fine here, since it's a 3rd party that you're overriding.
Also you can keep your `<style lang="scss" scoped>` this way.

As explained in the official vue loader documentation: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors

For more details, this post is always an excellent reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55368933/8816585

Comment: Thanks for replying. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the behavior after trying my solution ? :)

Comment: The css rule didn't manage to affect the actual color of the input. It's still white.

Comment: Did it appeared in the CSS computed part of the devtools at least ? Do you have a reproducible link to share ?

Comment: No it didn't appear nor in the Styles, nor in the Computed tab. Unfortunately I don't think it's possible to have a codepen or similar, since it requires a AWS account. I edited the question adding some instruction on how to setup the Vue sample, in case somebody is interested.