# How to dynamically switch a component based on the existence of window in Nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, dom, nuxt.js

I have a dynamic component that looks different at different screen resolutions.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <headerComponent></headerComponent>
    <div v-if="!large" class="placeholder"></div>
    <component
        v-else
        :is="tariffBlock"
    >
    </component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import smallComponent from '@/components/small-component'
  import largeComponent from '@/components/large-component'
  import headerComponent from '@/components/header-component'

  const components = {
    smallComponent,
    largeComponent
  }
  export default {
    components: {
      headerComponent
    },
    data () {
      return {
        large: false
      }
    },
    computed: {
      getComponent () {
        if (!this.large) return components.smallComponent
        return components.largeComponent
      }
    },
    created () {
      if (process.browser) {
        this.large = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 1200px)').matches
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

By default, a `smallComponent` is shown, and then a `largeComponent`. To avoid "jumping" I decided to show the `placeholder` while `large === false`.

To avoid the error `window in not defined` I use the check for `process.browser`.

PROBLEM: `placeholder` is only shown in `dev` mode, but when I start `generate`  the `placeholder` is not displayed.

The following solutions DIDN'T help:

1.

```
created () {
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    if (process.browser) {
      this.large = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 1200px)').matches
    }
  })
}
```

2. 

```
created () {
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.large = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 1200px)').matches
  })
}
```

3. 

```
mounted () {
  this.large = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 1200px)').matches
}
```

and with the addition `process.browser` and `nextTick()`

4. Creating a mixin with `ssr: false`, `mode: client`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: its better to enclose the component tag inside a div and place the v-else for that div

Comment: @Amaarrockz, Thank you. Is it more correct for architecture, or does it solve some problem?

Comment: Before I confirm that, can you please share the full code including template tags etc

Comment: `a dynamic component that looks different at different screen resolutions`, looks like a CSS solvable issue, with media queries. Not something to be done in JS.

Comment: @Amaarrockz, I edited the question to show more code.

Comment: You don't even need to import components in Nuxt. Maybe try a simpler example of importing a component depending of a button that you'll toggle from one to the other. Then look into the window size thing. Even if I still think you should be better server with CSS.

Comment: As Kissu said, you don't need to import components explicitly...nuxt does everything for you provided you need to give defined paths in the next.config.js

Comment: @kissu, I like the solution with styles, but the question remains, how to make Nuxt work correctly with window object

Comment: @denkhis CSS media queries are exactly this. Have a different style depending of the viewport (aka width, height, device type etc...). Baked into the browser already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you toggle between components in Nuxt.js

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div @click="toggleComponents">toggle components</div>
    <hr />
    <first-component></first-component>
    <second-component></second-component>
    <hr />
    <component :is="firstOrSecond"></component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      firstOrSecond: 'first-component',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleComponents() {
      if (this.firstOrSecond === 'first-component') {
        this.firstOrSecond = 'second-component'
      } else {
        this.firstOrSecond = 'first-component'
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

You don't need to import them, it's done automatically if you have the right configuration, as explained here: https://nuxtjs.org/blog/improve-your-developer-experience-with-nuxt-components

In this snippet of code, `first-component` and `second-component` are shown initially (between the two `hr`) just to be sure that you have them properly loaded already. You can of course remove them afterwards.

---

## Not recommended

This is what you're looking for. Again, this is **probably not** how you should handle some visual changes. Prefer CSS for this use-case.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <component :is="firstOrSecond"></component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      firstOrSecond: 'first-component',
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.toggleComponentDependingOfWindowWidth)
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    // important, otherwise you'll have the eventListener all over your SPA
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.toggleComponentDependingOfWindowWidth)
  },
  methods: {
    toggleComponentDependingOfWindowWidth() {
      console.log('current size of the window', window.innerWidth)

      if (window.innerWidth > 1200) {
        this.firstOrSecond = 'second-component'
      } else {
        this.firstOrSecond = 'first-component'
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

PS: if you **really** wish to use this solution, at least use a [throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#throttle) because the window event will trigger a lot and it can cause your UI to be super sluggish pretty quickly.

Comment: Found an interesting feature while using Nuxt Components. When I try to overwrite the styles of the child component in the parent, the styles in the parent are not applied. Have to put a flag ```!important```. 

When I import components directly, this does not happen. Is the use of ```!important``` a "crutch" in this case?

Comment: `!important` is not the way to go here. Prefer using deep selectors in this situation: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors This answer may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55368933/8816585 @denkhis