# vue - style not applied for extra component in same file

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I added some style on `.title` and `.description` in my stylesheet for my `test` component, but not sure why the style not applied.

```
const test = Vue.component("test", {
  template: `<div class="test">
    <span class="title">{{title}}</span>
    <div class="description">{{description}}</div>
  </div>`,
  props: {
    id: Number,
    title: String,
    description: String,
  },
});
```

[image]

HelloWorld.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="hello">
    <test
      v-for="item in steps"
      :key="item.id"
      :id="item.id"
      :title="item.title"
      :description="item.description"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from "vue";

const test = Vue.component("test", {
  template: `<div class="test">
    <span class="title">{{title}}</span>
    <div class="description">{{description}}</div>
  </div>`,
  props: {
    id: Number,
    title: String,
    description: String,
  },
});

export default {
  components: {
    test,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      steps: [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: "What is Lorem Ipsum?",
          description:
            "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
<style scoped lang="scss">
#hello {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  .test {
    /* style applied */
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    .title {
      /* style not applied */
      font-size: 50px;
      color: orange;
    }
    .description {
      /* style not applied */
      font-size: 10px;
      line-height: 12px;
      color: red;
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

Codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-flower-rcvob?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using scoped styles, the styles will only apply to direct elements in the corresponding template. The `title` and `description` elements are child elements of the `<test>` component and are unaffected by scoped styles of another component.

You need to use [`::v-deep`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48032006/how-do-i-use-deep-or-or-v-deep-in-vue-js) if you want the style to apply to a child element of another component:

```
#hello {
  .test {
    &::v-deep .title {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

I couldn't get this to work in codesandbox though. It might be a configuration issue. See also [Deep Selectors](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors).