# How can i delete the default icon in vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, combobox, vuetify.js

[image]

I am using vuetify. I needed the "v-combobox" tag, but it has an arrow icon by default, I rummaged through the Vuetify documentation and it didn't help to understand how to remove it, what can I do without losing the application logic? Maby i can kill it at html lvl?

```
<template>
<v-app>
    <v-combobox
        v-model="chips"
        :items="items"
        chips
        clearable
        multiple
        solo>
        <template v-slot:selection="{ item }">
            <v-chip close @click:close="remove(item)">
                <strong>{{ item }}</strong
                >&nbsp;
            </v-chip>
        </template>
    </v-combobox>
</v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "Test",
    data: () => ({
        chips: ["hello", "stack", "overflow"],
    }),
    methods: {
        remove(item) {
            this.chips.splice(this.chips.indexOf(item), 1);
            this.chips = [...this.chips];
            },
        }
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this prop to the combobox :append-icon="null" 
Have a read of docs here https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-combobox/#links

```
      <v-combobox
        v-model="chips"
        :items="items"
        chips
        clearable
        multiple
        solo
        :append-icon="null">
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this codesandbox I made: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-71683514-hide-combobox-arrow-icon-yuto05?file=/src/components/Example.vue

[image: Example]

If you just want to hide the icon for an expecific combobox, you can do it with CSS, in this example I just created an special class named `noicon-combo`, and configured like this:

```html
<v-col cols="12">
  <v-combobox
    v-model="select"
    class="noicon-combo"
    :items="items"
    label="Combobox No Icon"
    multiple
    outlined
    dense
  ></v-combobox>

  <v-combobox
    v-model="select"
    :items="items"
    label="Combobox"
    multiple
    outlined
    dense
  ></v-combobox>
</v-col>
```

```css
/* Normal version */
.noicon-combo .v-select__slot .v-input__icon {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```css
/* Scoped version */
.noicon-combo >>>.v-select__slot .v-input__icon {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: If it were that easy, I wouldn't post here :( Tried it doesn't work

Comment: And, it seems to have happened, I deleted the scoped property and it turned out, but I hope this will not affect other 'select' tags

Comment: Actually, it's that easy. Are you using `scoped` css?

Comment: yes, but I have other select tags, I hope this property does not affect everything globally

Comment: Ah okay, when you are using `scoped` sometimes you might need to use deep selectors. If you want to hide the icon on an specific combobox, then you can create an special class for it. I'll set up an example in codesandbox for you.

Comment: There you go. I updated my answer.

Comment: yes, thnx, it work's!

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot. But if using Sass OR using Vue 3, ref.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48032006/how-do-i-use-deep-or-or-v-deep-in-vue-js