# Remove box-shadow from Vuetify component

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

## I have

an **expanded-row-table** from Vuetify, it came with box shadow on the row while **expanded**

[image]

## I want

to remove the box-shadow, I checked the console-style tab, I see

[image]

so I decided to add this code in the bottom of my `show.vue`

```
.v-data-table > .v-data-table__wrapper tbody tr.v-data-table__expanded__content {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

I don't see any effect, shadow still there.

Comment: You maybe need a [deep selector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55368933/8816585)? If you cannot see your `box-shadow: none` CSS property, something is missing in terms of scope/reach to the given component.

Comment: You're correct, it's working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55368933/8816585), you may use deep selectors.

In your case, this seems to work

```css
>>> .v-data-table > .v-data-table__wrapper tbody tr.v-data-table__expanded__content {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to put it in a style tag that is not scoped (i.e without the scoped).

Like

```
<style>
 .v-data-table > .v-data-table__wrapper tbody tr.v-data-table__expanded__content {
   box-shadow: none !important;
 }
</style>
```