# vue scss :deep() error on direct child selector

Tags: vue.js, sass

I need to deep-target all direct child divs of an element.

`&:deep(>div)` works, but produces these errors:

[image: editor screenshot]

first error says: `} expected`

second error says: `at-rule or selector expected`

`&:deep(div)` doesn't highlight as an error, but is not exactly what I need.

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Try to target a class instead of HTML selector. More info here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48032006/how-do-i-use-deep-or-or-v-deep-in-vue-js

Comment: yeah but I need to target multiple direct ancestor divs of various classes