# How to target html tag element with :v-deep() selector?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3

When I use:

```
::v-deep img { ... }
```

it works but I get a deprecation warning:

```
[@vue/compiler-sfc] ::v-deep usage as a combinator has been deprecated. Use :deep(<inner-selector>) instead.
```

How do I do the same thing but with `:v-deep(img)`?

```
:v-deep(img) { ... }
```

results in `unknown pseudo selector error`.

**`Edit:`**

If I could target a `class` I would but in my case I'm trying to target `html tags` inside a `rich text editor` to which classes can not be applied.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#scoped-css

Answer (score 1):

You are putting v- before deep because of which you're getting unknown selector error
try out this piece of code

```
:deep(img){
/* Your styles  */
}
```

Comment: yes I've tried that but I'm getting the error mentioned in my question

Answer (score 0):

```
:deep(.child-class) {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

You can read more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48032006/how-do-i-use-deep-or-or-v-deep-in-vue-js)