# How to change this Vue3 ::v-deep SASS syntax to use :deep?

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vuejs3

HTML:

```
<template>
 <form class="bg-white">
  <div class="source-field">
...
```

Here's the original SASS:

```
.form::v-deep
  .source-field
    width: 129px
    display: inline-block
    margin: 0px 2px 5px 2px
```

Changing it to this does not work, none of the styles apply anymore:

```
:deep(.form)
  .source-field
    width: 129px
    display: inline-block
    margin: 0px 2px 5px 2px
```

This works too:

```
::v-deep
  .source-field
    width: 129px
    display: inline-block
    margin: 0px 2px 5px 2px
```

But this does not:

```
:deep()
  .source-field
    width: 129px
    display: inline-block
    margin: 0px 2px 5px 2px
```

Comment: I had a similar problem and for me the <style> tag was missing the "scoped".

Answer (score 0):

Documentation: https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#scoped-css

> If you want a selector in `scoped` styles to be "deep", i.e. affecting child components, you can use the `:deep()` pseudo-class:
>
> ```html
> <style scoped>
> .a :deep(.b) {
>   /* ... */
> }
> </style>
> ```

An answer with a good explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55368933

Solution for your case:

You basically have `.form::v-deep .source-field`, where `.form` is the accessible parent that you want to take as the base, which can also be written as `.form >>> .source-field`(*SASS can't parse it, but it's an example for understanding it*). So, with the new `:deep()`, you combine it with the parent before it and pass the child name as a "parameter". (*e.g. `.parent :deep(.child)`*)

Given all these, for your case the solution would be `.form :deep(.source-field)`, if you want to keep the nested selectors, you can do:

```
.form
  :deep(.source-field)
    width: 129px
    display: inline-block
    margin: 0px 2px 5px 2px
```