# When scoped in Nuxt.js, child elements are not styled

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, nuxt.js

I'm using v2 of Nuxt.js.
If css is loaded under the following conditions, no style will be set on the child elements.

- Import scss file with style settings with style tag
- Add `scoped` to the style tag above.

Below is a demo.
[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/importing-sass-in-vue-forked-u9iq58?file=/src/assets/style.scss)
It can be confirmed that the style for the elements under header in `/assets/style.scss` is not set.

```css
header {
  background: #dddddd;

  > ul { // not working
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
  }

  button { // not working
    background: black;
    color: white;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to style child elements in the form of importing scss?

---

The main codes are as follows.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Header />

    <HelloWorld />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from "./components/Header";
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Header,
    HelloWorld,
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "./assets/style.scss";
</style>
```

```
// Header.vue
<template>
  <header>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h1>{{ appName }}</h1>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button>Sign in</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </header>
</template>
```

```css
// style.scss

header {
  background: #dddddd;

  > ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
  }

  button {
    background: black;
    color: white;
  }
}

.hello {
  background: #efefef;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: remove `scoped`, it won't allow you to set child component CSS

Comment: Without scoped, css will be read even on pages that do not need to be loaded.

Comment: that's why you should move `header {}` into header.vue then scope it, all that should go in App.vue is vendor or global styles, like for layout. You cant add scoped then expect things to be global

Comment: You probably need to use that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55368933/8816585

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its CSS will apply to elements of the current component only. So you need to append below code

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "../assets/style.scss";
</style>
```

at Header.vue to make the css file effected.

Comment: then it will import it twice, bloating out the CSS for no reason

Comment: of course you need to remove the css at App.vue. It's better to write css file for each components instead of writing them into a single file

Comment: No matter how small the css file is, it is necessary to create a css file for each component, and we would like to avoid that method.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).