# Different color for date cell on month view using Vue Cal?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm pretty new on Vue Cal VueJS 3. I need help on this.

I have these events data which have boolean condition. if true, display green color otherwise red color.

I refer to Vue Cal documentation, and right now I don't have idea how can I set different background color to date cell on month view calendar.

In inspect element, I can see that I need to adjust the class of `.vuecal__cell--selected` to achieve my goal . But I'm not sure how to add it inside `<vue-cal><vue-cal>` component.

[image]

This is what I achieve so far.

**Component.vue**

```html
<template>
  <vue-cal
    class="vuecal--blue-theme"
    selected-date="2022-08-25"
    xsmall
    :disable-views="['years', 'year', 'week', 'day']"
    active-view="month"
    :events-on-month-views="true"
    :events="calendarEvents"
    hide-view-selector
    :time="false" 
    style="width: 300px; height: 262px"
  >
    <template #events-count="{ events }"> 
      <span :style="{ backgroundColor: '#00FF00' }" v-if="eventWorkingDay(events) === true"
        >1
        <span :style="{ backgroundColor: '#00FF00' }" v-if="eventIsAvailable(events) === true">1</span>
        <span :style="{ backgroundColor: '#FF0000' }" v-else>1</span>
      </span>
      <span :style="{ backgroundColor: '#FF0000' }" v-else>1</span>
    </template> 
  </vue-cal>
</template>

<script>
import vuecal from 'vue-cal';
import 'vue-cal/dist/vuecal.css';
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue'; 

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Calendar',
  components: {
    'vue-cal': vuecal,
  }, 
  setup() { 

    const calendarEvents = ref([
      {
        id: '01',
        start: '2022-08-01',
        end: '2022-08-01',
        name: 'Event Name 01',
        isWorkingDay: false,
        isAvailable: false,
      },
      {
        id: '02',
        start: '2022-08-02',
        end: '2022-08-02',
        name: 'Event Name 02',
        isWorkingDay: false,
        isAvailable: false,
      },
      {
        id: '03',
        start: '2022-08-03',
        end: '2022-08-03',
        name: 'Event Name 03',
        isWorkingDay: false,
        isAvailable: false,
      }
    ]);

    const eventCount = (calendarEvents) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < calendarEvents.length; i++) {
        let cond = calendarEvents[i].isWorkingDay;

        if (cond === true) {
          return 0;
        } else {
          return 1;
        }
      }
    };

    const eventWorkingDay = (calendarEvents) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < calendarEvents.length; i++) {
        let cond = calendarEvents[i].isWorkingDay;

        if (cond === true) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
    };

    const eventIsAvailable = (calendarEvents) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < calendarEvents.length; i++) {
        let cond = calendarEvents[i].isAvailable;

        if (cond === true) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
    };

    return {
      inputs, 
      eventCount,
      eventWorkingDay,
      eventIsAvailable,
      calendarEvents,
    };
  },
});
</script>

<style scoped>
.vuecal__cell-events-count {
  background: transparent;
}
</style>
```

**Current Output :**

[image]

**Expected Output :** I want to fill date cell to background-color like this.

[image]

Appreciate if someone can help me on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change template events count into cell content. After that, you can control cell content color in setup function and pass it back into template

**Component.vue**

```
<template>
  <vue-cal
    class="vuecal--blue-theme"
    selected-date="2022-08-25"
    xsmall
    :disable-views="['years', 'year', 'week', 'day']"
    active-view="month"
    :events-on-month-views="true"
    :events="calendarEvents"
    hide-view-selector
    :time="false" 
    style="width: 300px; height: 262px"
  >
    <template #cell-content="{ cell, view }">
            <div class="vuecal__cell-date full-height column justify-center" :class="[view.id, getColorClass(cell)]" v-if="view.id === 'month'">
                {{ cell.content }}
            </div>
        </template> 
  </vue-cal>
</template>

<script>
import vuecal from 'vue-cal';
import 'vue-cal/dist/vuecal.css';
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue'; 

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Calendar',
  components: {
    'vue-cal': vuecal,
  }, 
  setup() { 

    const calendarEvents = ref([
      {
        id: '01',
        start: '2022-08-01',
        end: '2022-08-01',
        name: 'Event Name 01',
        isWorkingDay: false,
        isAvailable: false,
      },
      {
        id: '02',
        start: '2022-08-02',
        end: '2022-08-02',
        name: 'Event Name 02',
        isWorkingDay: false,
        isAvailable: false,
      },
      {
        id: '03',
        start: '2022-08-03',
        end: '2022-08-03',
        name: 'Event Name 03',
        isWorkingDay: false,
        isAvailable: false,
      }
    ]);

    const eventCount = (calendarEvents) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < calendarEvents.length; i++) {
        let cond = calendarEvents[i].isWorkingDay;

        if (cond === true) {
          return 0;
        } else {
          return 1;
        }
      }
    };

    const eventWorkingDay = (calendarEvents) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < calendarEvents.length; i++) {
        let cond = calendarEvents[i].isWorkingDay;

        if (cond === true) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
    };

    const eventIsAvailable = (calendarEvents) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < calendarEvents.length; i++) {
        let cond = calendarEvents[i].isAvailable;

        if (cond === true) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
    };
    
    const getColorClass = (cell) => {
        if (!cell.outOfScope) {
            const res = props.calendarEvents;
            for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                if (cell.formattedDate === res[i].start && res[i].isWorkingDay == true) {
                    if (cell.formattedDate === res[i].start && res[i].isAvailable == true) {
                        return 'bg-green-2';
                    } else {
                        return 'bg-red-2';
                    }
                } else if (cell.formattedDate === res[i].start && res[i].isWorkingDay == false) {
                    return 'bg-red-2';
                }

                if (cell.today) {
                    return 'bg-orange text-white';
                }
            }

            return 'bg-grey-3';
        }

        return '';
    };

    return {
      inputs, 
      eventCount,
      eventWorkingDay,
      eventIsAvailable,
      calendarEvents,
      getColorClass,
    };
  },
});
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you need to find out the concerned class (as you did). Then, go to the closest component you have access to and use a [deep selector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55368933/8816585) to mutate it deep down. Sometimes, an `!important` may also be required of course.

Depending of your Vue version and if you're using SASS or not, you may need to write it like that

```css
>>> .vuecal__cell--selected {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Tq for the reply. I tried it (deep selector) but none of it working so far.

Comment: @RzjEM this is the way to go if there is nothing in the documentation of the package specific to customizing styles. Do you have a [repro] or alike? Because it should work pretty well overall.

Comment: yea . I just found out the solution after few days trying . Thanks !

Comment: @RzjEM so, what was it?