# How to apply style to few of many buttons in Vue.js app?

Tags: css, vue.js, devextreme

The code looks as following:

```
<template>
  <DxPopup
    v-bind="$attrs"
    v-on="$listeners"
    :hide-on-outside-click="true"
    :drag-enabled="true"
    :wrapper-attr="popupAttributes"
    position="center"
    @hiding="onHiding"
  >
    <slot />
    <slot name="footer">
      <DxToolbarItem class="btn-default" widget="dxButton" toolbar="bottom" :options="okButtonOptions" />
      <DxToolbarItem class="btn-default" widget="dxButton" toolbar="bottom" :options="closeButtonOptions" />
    </slot>
  </DxPopup>
</template>
```

```
<script>
import { DxPopup } from 'devextreme-vue/popup';
import { DxToolbarItem } from 'devextreme-vue/popup';

export default {
    inheritAttrs: false,
    components: {
        DxPopup,
        DxToolbarItem
    },
    data() {
        return {
            popupAttributes: {
                id: 'popup-base',
            },
```

```
<style lang="scss">
#popup-base .dx-popup-normal {
  border-radius: 20px;
}
#popup-base .dx-texteditor-input {
  color: #8ca8cc;
  font-family: $primary-font-family;
  font-size: 15px;
}
#popup-base .dx-popup-title {
  border-bottom: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: $font-xl;
  color: $accent-color;
}
#popup-base .dx-label {
  color: $accent-color;
}
#popup-base .dx-button-content {
  border: 1px solid $accent-color;
  color: $accent-color;
}
</style>
```

The modal dialog looks as following:

[image]

How to apply `#popup-base .dx-button-content` rule only to two buttons at the bottom?

Comment: By adding dx-button-content to `class`? It's unknown what the components are in the example and how they work

Comment: Are you working with vue 2 or 3?

Comment: @Estus Flask: I work with DevExtreme components.

Comment: @Boussadjra Brahim: Vue 2.

Comment: Can't you use some CSS selectors for those? After inspecting them with your devtools?

Comment: Then the question is very specific to them

Comment: @kissu: I've tried a lot, but nothing is working.

Comment: If you target them properly (thanks to your devtools) + use a [deep selector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55368933/8816585), it should work out.

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
export default {
    inheritAttrs: false,
    components: {
        DxPopup,
        DxToolbarItem
    },
    data() {
        return {
            popupAttributes: {
                id: 'popup-base',
            },
            okButtonOptions: {
                text: 'Сохранить',
                elementAttr: {
                    class: 'btn-default'
                },
```

```
<style lang="scss">
.btn-default {
    border: 1px solid $accent-color;
    color: $accent-color;
}
```