# Upgrading to Vuetify 2.6.12

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, package.json, node-sass, sass-loader

I’m trying to upgrade Vuetify package to version 2.6.12 in my project Vuejs. Therefore, I’ve gotten error message when I run “npm run serve”

> Error:
> Syntax Error: SassError: expected selector.
> ╷
> 2 │ /deep/ #btn-acoes-t button:nth-child(3){ display: none !important;}
> │ ^
> ╵
> src\views\PerfilAnoLetivo.vue 2:1 root stylesheet

> @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref–8-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader??ref–8-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref–8-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref–8-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref–0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/PerfilAnoLetivo.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=33337f33&lang=scss&scoped=true& 4:14-467 15:3-20:5 16:22-475
> @ ./src/views/PerfilAnoLetivo.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=33337f33&lang=scss&scoped=true&
> @ ./src/views/PerfilAnoLetivo.vue
> @ ./src/routes/gerencial.js
> @ ./src/routes/layout.js
> @ ./src/routes/index.js
> @ ./src/main.js
> @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "educacaoapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "lint-fix": "vue-cli-service lint --fix"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^12.0.0",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^6.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "pdfmake": "^0.2.6",
    "vue": "^2.6.6",
    "vue-chartjs": "^3.4.0",
    "vue-debounce": "^4.0.0",
    "vue-gravatar": "^1.4.1",
    "vue-progressbar": "^0.7.5",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.2",
    "vue-the-mask": "^0.11.1",
    "vue-tour": "^2.0.0",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.7",
    "vuetify": "^2.6.12",
    "vuex": "^3.1.0",
    "vuex-persistedstate": "^2.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.4",
    "@mdi/font": "^7.0.96",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.4.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-standard": "^3.0.5",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.2.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.13",
    "sass": "^1.56.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1"
  }
}
```

node version v14.20.1
npm version: 6.14.17

I tried remove node_modules && npm install
I tried remove node-sass package
I installed package sass-loader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector should be written like this when using SASS

```css
::v-deep #btn-acoes-t button:nth-child(3)
```

as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55368933/8816585).