Override SASS variables for a Vuetify3 Component
I would like to globally customize the style of some Vuetify Components. Vuetify seems to have a SASS API where I can override variables to customize components. However, I cannot figure out how to change, e.g., the font-family, size, and letter-spacing for buttons only.
I've set up treeshaking and created a settings.scss that successfully overrides the default font:
@use 'vuetify/settings' with (
    $utilities: false,
    $color-pack: true,

    $body-font-family: $font,
    $font-size-root: 16px, 
);

That way, I can override the variables in _variables.scss. The Variable API suggests I could simply add, e.g.,  $button-font-size: 100px to override a component's style. However, this doesn't change anything. Inspecting with chrome reveals that the font-size is still determined by
.v-btn--size-default {
    --v-btn-size: 0.875rem;
    font-size: var(--v-btn-size);
}

Of course, I could add something like .v-btn { font-size: 100px !important; }, but I guess meddling with the css on that level is not very robust and could easily break in future updates. Thats why I would like to use the feature that was intended to customize the styles. Or am I on the wrong path here and this API is not intended to customize Vuetify components?

You do not see something similar to $button-font-size: 100px being overridden in the browser devtools?

No, I searched for everything containing the phrase "font-size" and only found this one. So, it should work like what I attempted there?

If you're following the docs properly should work yes. Maybe you need a deep selector for the CSS tho: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55368933/8816585

Could you provide a reproduction link, maybe on StackBlitz?
